# X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) when runing Conky

Tags: conky

When Trying to run conky with a custom configuration I get the following output:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  55 (X_CreateGC)
  Serial number of failed request:  98
  Current serial number in output stream:  99
```

This is actually a brand new installation of Ubuntu Gnome 14.10. Nothing extra installed yet.

This is the complete output of the command:

```
root@Ndavellir:/home/luke/.conky-themes/ConkyWorkspace# conky -c conkyrc-workspace
Conky: conkyrc-workspace: 25: no such configuration: 'border_margin'
Conky: conkyrc-workspace: 35: config file error: default_bar_size takes 2 integer     arguments (ie. 'default_bar_size 0 6')
Conky: forked to background, pid is 3252
root@Ndavellir:/home/luke/.conky-themes/ConkyWorkspace# 
Conky: desktop window (1000023) is subwindow of root window (28b)
Conky: drawing to desktop window
Conky: drawing to single buffer
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  55 (X_CreateGC)
  Serial number of failed request:  98
  Current serial number in output stream:  99
```

I've searched in Goolge for the better part of the afternoon without success. Can anyone tell me what this means and how I can correct it please?. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Keep configuring conky (at least this worked for me):

```
    own_window_type desktop
    #own_window_type override
    own_window_transparent yes
    #own_window_transparent no
```